# POST call to SailsJS api showing JSON parse error

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, http-post, sails.js

I'm trying to put some data in mysql database using sails js API, 
Here is my data which I'm sending via ajax call

```
{"person":{"name":"Sahasrangshu Guha","address":"Dlf It Park Ii Block 1a, Plot No. Ii-F/1, Action A, Ericsson Kolkata","phoneNumber":"9830612244"}}
```

Here is the ajax call header

```
{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'responseType': 'json' }
```

My sails js controller is as follows

```
module.exports = {

addPerson: function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST' && req.param('person', null) != null) {
        console.log(req.param('person'));
        Person.create(req.param('person'), (error, person) => {
            if(error) {
                res.send('Error:Sorry!Something went Wrong');
            } else {
                res.send('Successfully Created!');
            }
        });

            // Error handling
            // if (err) {
            //     res.send('Error:Sorry!Something went Wrong');
            // } else {}
            //     res.send('Successfully Created!');
            //     //res.redirect( ‘person/view/’+model.id);
            // }

    }
    else {
        res.send('Error:Sorry!Data Wrong');
    }
}
}
```

And my sails js model looks like below

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'person',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  attributes: {
  name: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
 }
  }

};
```

I'm alaways having the following error whenver I'm making a POST request to my sails js API

> {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()

Any idea to solve this? I have tried sending object rather than JSON data but the same error pursues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While returning the response I think an Object is being expected instead of String here
     `res.send(errObj);`
where error obj should be something like

```
{
success: false,
status: 400,
message : 'Error:Sorry!Something went Wrong'
}
```

Or send the message with status code

```
res.status(response.status || 500).send(response)
```

Comment: Thanks , I was thinking the problem was in my request body but actually the problem was for my response data.

Comment: I'm glad it solved your query, cud u upvote my answer?